# How dangerous a threat does North Korea pose to the world?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, nuclear-weapons, united-nations, north-korea

Current news states that North Korea have been ignoring UN resolutions on nuclear development, and have gone ahead with development and testing of nuclear weapons. They have stated that they can, and if necessary, will go ahead with a nuclear strike on the US, thus bringing into action, a US counteraction in the pacific, as a deterrent against nuclear warfare.

Given that China (the world's most prominent emerging superpower, alongside India) is currently North Korea's biggest ally, this seems like a recipe for disaster, should North Korea launch such an attack on the US.

Should such an event occur, I would like to know how this will affect the nations of the world?

Comment: Hi! This is extremely interesting, but at the same time is not really a question that can be answered definitively, all we can offer is speculation. That's not really what the site is about, we tend to avoid open ended discussions and focus on questions that can be answered with facts and referenced, and hopefully definitively. If you would like to further discuss the closing of the question, feel free to post a question about it on our [Meta site](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If North Korea strikes against the US, neither China nor India will back them.  China is not a big enough ally to do that, and neither is India.  That aside, North Korea's missiles can't even reach the United States.  They may go after SK, but that would be suicide since they know they won't win against the US.  Unless NK has partnered with China behind our backs to destroy the world, the only thing that could happen would be a failed attack on SK.  Also, if they do invade SK, that would give the US permission to invade NK, and I doubt Kim Jong Un wants that.  I would say that they're just bluffing.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE!  This is a good answer, but it would be even better if you could support your assertions.  To claim that China would not back North Korea - while I suspect in a first-strike is correct - is not a foregone conclusion.  Appealing to other pundits or analyses would help this answer alot!

Comment: WikiLeaks substantiated these claims. Would have to dig up the link(s), but they clearly showed China was not in favor of the DPRK - especially their posturing.

Comment: DPRK threatens no one. Their nuke device is good for a land mine at best. The U.S. hyped up DPRK's threat in order to justify its military presence.

Comment: "North Korea's missiles can't even reach the United States." I think this answer needs updating.